# sql - insert a new row for every customer id that is in the table

Tags: sql, insert

I am using SQL server 2008. The following is my table:

```
Cust_id  Date           rate    type
3579    12/05/2014     0.01256   f
5200    13/05/2014     0.02365   f
1234    18/05/2014     0.05623   m
3456    23/05/2014     0.01254   m
7896    23/05/2014     0.01254   f
2589    21/05/2014     0.01254   m
3698    23/05/2014     0.01254   f
```

I would like to select all the customers that are type 'm' (that is easy enough) and I would like to insert a new row of Date,rate and type for each customer that is found. so the result would look something like this:

```
Cust_id  Date           rate     type
1234    18/05/2014      0.05623   m
1234    16/05/2014      0.02222   f
3456    23/05/2014      0.01254   m
3456    27/05/2014      0.03333   f
2589    21/05/2014      0.01254   m
2589    20/05/2014      0.01111   f
```

I will not be able to insert rows individually because I have over 5000 customers :-(. Could some experts assist me.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can compute *required* `Date`, `Rate` and `Type` from *selected* `Date`, `Rate` and `Type` you can use **insert..select** construction:

```
insert into Customers(
  Cust_id, 
  Date,
  Rate,
  Type)

  select Cust_id, 
         Date, -- TODO:Generate required Date from given one
         Rate, -- TODO:Generate required Rate from given one
         Type  -- TODO:Generate required Type from given one
    from Customers 
   where Type = 'm'
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax